# Changing page style on button click in Jekyll blog (with js or liquid templating)

Tags: javascript, html, button, jekyll, liquid

I am updating the default template of a Jekyll blog, and want to change the style used on a button click. I have everything working without the button using Liquid templating, as in if I add
`{%- include style_b.html -%}` then the style will change.

But I am trying to add a button going back and forth from style 'a' to style 'b' when clicked.  I've added the button like so:
`<button type="button" name="change_style" onclick=ChangeStyle();>change page style</button>`
so that the button being linked calls a .js function:

```
function ChangeStyle() {
  $("#result").load("../_includes/style_b.html");
  console.log("loaded")
}
```

This isn't actually changing the style and even if it was I don't know how I would undo that. Is there a way to do this that works in Jekyll? Can't find any solution let alone one that adheres to best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to _includes in your _site directory once Jekyll has built the site. You'll need to make `style_a.html` and `style_b.html` a standalone page and not an include, or make those changes in CSS so you can target them with Javascript.